# AMD Underscan on CLI

Tags: 13.04, command-line, ati

SO I installed Ubuntu 13.04 minimal from a server installation. CLI worked fine, and I added Xorg and XBMC so I could have a CLI server, but the option to start X and login using XBMC-Live.

I have an HD5450 gfx, which had no issues on CLI. I installed the proprietary drivers from AMD's site and started X, XBMC, which underscanned on my Philips 23" monitor.

I dropped to terminal, ran

`sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-val=MCIL,DigitalHDTVDefaultUnderscan,0`

and rebooted. Now CLI interface, before I start X, is underscanning, but when in X/XBMC it works perfectly.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or why this would be?

I have scoured the internet and tried re-installing X/drivers and clearing settings and xorg.conf to no avail.